# How to control refresh interval

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm hosting an intranet website by WordPress 3.6 on Centos 6.4 .
I noticed that when users access to intranet website, after browsing some pages, leave browser opened, their browser will refresh intranet website after 5 seconds. In my intranet website access log, I get entries like this:

```
192.168.14.185 - - [26/Aug/2014:11:54:49 +0700] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2
...
192.168.14.185 - - [26/Aug/2014:11:54:54 +0700] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2
...
192.168.14.185 - - [26/Aug/2014:11:54:59 +0700] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2
...
```

How can I control it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that some of the pages calling the AJAX method after a certain interval. Now you need to find the Method which is responsible for that. You may use the NETWORK option in Browser to find which method has been called, and then find it and rectify that if required.